# How to implement async-await pattern for iText 7?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, async-await, itext, itext7

Why does the iText sharper library do not expose any asynchronous method?

I'm used to using the APM methods `MethodNameAsync()` from libraries. It confused me a bit because iText did not expose APM methods. 
Is there any reason for this? Reading and manipulating PDF's does not require asynchronous programming?

I will be using PDF reads on an ASP.Net Core controller. In case to gain performance and parallelism, would not it be crucial to read the PDF asynchronously?

Comment: What is stopping you from making it async yourself?

Comment: I'm used to using the APM methods xxxxAsync() from libraries. It confused me a bit because iText did not expose APM Async methods.

Comment: You have no control over that but you can wrap them in your own async calls.

Comment: So I should create a PdfReader wrapper class and use something like Task.Run to return a Task from PdfReader(iText) sync class? Okay, but my biggest doubt is why iText does not expose any asynchronous patterns? What would be the real reason for this. Neither in .NET nor in Java. I was a little confused and thought that it is not necessary to use async for PDF readings

Comment: Only they can answer that. Trying to guess why it just a waste of time.

Comment: What APIs is iText 7 providing?

Comment: Note: making it asynchronous increases availability but decreases performance for the individual request.

Comment: @Gustavo it does not make sense to make an async  variant of each and every method around. Which iText method or functionality would you want an async variant of and why?

Comment: @mkl I want to make PdfReader => PdfDocument => PdfPage => PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage async to get text from PDF without blocking ASP.Net WebAPI calls

Comment: In that case consider putting that whole sequence into a Task for asynchronous execution. This would also explain to you why iText does not already include async methods: the natural blocks of code to make asynchronous contain multiple iText API calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the first question:

> Why does the iText sharper library do not expose any asynchronous method?

Generally, it's good practice to expose async methods for operations which are naturally asynchronous, such as network or file operations which are not CPU-bound. For a thorough explanation of why, see Stephen Cleary's excellent [post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html), but suffice to say that operations on in-memory PDF documents are highly likely to be CPU-bound, and aren't likely to offer any benefits to being wrapped in an async method, but in fact would come at a cost, if all these methods did was something like a `Task.Run(...)`.

If you need to avoid blocking your application's main thread by doing CPU-bound work (such as in a UI application), you can use `Task.Run()` to accomplish this, something like the following:

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    // Run numerous CPU-bound PDF operations using iTextSharp...
    var text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page);
    // Run more CPU-bound PDF operations...
});
```

The important point is: this approach allows you, the API consumer, to decide how to handle the fact that making so many calls to the iText SDK involves mostly operating on the CPU.

> Reading and manipulating PDF's does not require asynchronous programming?

Reading, perhaps, depending on where it was reading it from. I think they are trying to supply you a uniform interface for reading a PDF from multiple places, some of which won't be I/O bound.

> I will be using PDF reads on an ASP.Net Core controller. In case to gain performance and parallelism, would not it be crucial to read the PDF asynchronously?

Also outlined in Stephen's post, linked earlier, **using thread-pool threads on ASP.NET is a bad idea**. Not only will allocating another thread-pool thread to the one request not help your performance in, it will will also reduce those available to other requests (and thus limit the server's ability to handle more requests), among numerous other problems.

On the topic of parallelism, this is something web servers excel at. They can handle many requests at once! So if your request reads or generates a PDF, each ASP.NET controller action can do so synchronously, and other requests will still be handled by the web server. You are only likely to encounter issues if your PDF operations really take a long time to run. If so, you should consider running them out-of-band using [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/), or similar, and email the user when the operations are done.